# Why doesn't this Direct2D geometry group fill

Tags: visual-c++, directx, direct2d

Here is one complicated way to draw the rectangle. However, it is taken from a more complex example where rectangle corners are different geometries. I am trying to understand the principle involved because I am clearly missing something.

Namely, when I draw the geometry group, returned from the function below, I **do** get a rectangle drawn. When I try to fill the geometry group it **doesn't** get filled. The question is why.

I played with various parameters to path geometry for each line but nothing seems to work. Per documentation, the only thing that should matter is the correct orientation of the geometries added to a geometry group and I believe that all the lines are correctly oriented, going in a clockwise direction.

Here is the code:

```
    CComPtr<ID2D1GeometryGroup> Test(ID2D1Factory* factory, RECT& r)
    {

    CComPtr<ID2D1PathGeometry> tLine;
    CComPtr<ID2D1PathGeometry> rLine;
    CComPtr<ID2D1PathGeometry> bLine;
    CComPtr<ID2D1PathGeometry> lLine;


    //top horizontal line geometry
    {
        auto hr = factory->CreatePathGeometry(&tLine);
        CComPtr<ID2D1GeometrySink> sink;
        hr = tLine->Open(&sink);
        sink->SetFillMode(D2D1_FILL_MODE_WINDING);

        sink->BeginFigure(
            D2D1::Point2F(r.left, r.top),
            D2D1_FIGURE_BEGIN_HOLLOW
        );

        sink->AddLine(D2D1::Point2F(r.right, r.top));
        sink->EndFigure(D2D1_FIGURE_END_OPEN);
        sink->Close();
    }

    //right vertical line geometry
    {
        auto hr = factory->CreatePathGeometry(&rLine);
        CComPtr<ID2D1GeometrySink> sink;
        hr = rLine->Open(&sink);
        sink->SetFillMode(D2D1_FILL_MODE_WINDING);

        sink->BeginFigure(
            D2D1::Point2F(r.right, r.top),
            D2D1_FIGURE_BEGIN_HOLLOW
        );

        sink->AddLine(D2D1::Point2F(r.right, r.bottom));
        sink->EndFigure(D2D1_FIGURE_END_OPEN);
        sink->Close();
    }

    //bottom horizontal line geometry
    {
        auto hr = factory->CreatePathGeometry(&bLine);
        CComPtr<ID2D1GeometrySink> sink;
        hr = bLine->Open(&sink);
        sink->SetFillMode(D2D1_FILL_MODE_WINDING);

        sink->BeginFigure(
            D2D1::Point2F(r.right, r.bottom),
            D2D1_FIGURE_BEGIN_HOLLOW
        );

        sink->AddLine(D2D1::Point2F(r.left, r.bottom));
        sink->EndFigure(D2D1_FIGURE_END_OPEN);
        sink->Close();
    }

    //left vertical line geometry
    {
        auto hr = factory->CreatePathGeometry(&lLine);
        CComPtr<ID2D1GeometrySink> sink;
        hr = lLine->Open(&sink);
        sink->SetFillMode(D2D1_FILL_MODE_WINDING);
        sink->BeginFigure(
            D2D1::Point2F(r.left, r.bottom),
            D2D1_FIGURE_BEGIN_HOLLOW
        );

        sink->AddLine(D2D1::Point2F(r.left, r.top));
        sink->EndFigure(D2D1_FIGURE_END_OPEN);
        sink->Close();
    }


    ID2D1Geometry *ppGeometries[] =
    {
        tLine,
        rLine,
        bLine,
        lLine
    };

    CComPtr<ID2D1GeometryGroup> group;
    auto hr = factory->CreateGeometryGroup(
        D2D1_FILL_MODE_WINDING,
        ppGeometries,
        4,
        &group);

    return group;
}
```

Comment: I don't think those separate lines are supposed to be combined into a single closed (fillable) figure when you create a geometry group.

Comment: This is just an example. Often you are given an open geometry so you have a starting point and an endpoint for it. Now you want to connect some lines to that geometry and make it a closed geometry. You want to be able to fill it with a brush. I don't see how can that be accomplished if it cannot be demonstrated on this example.

Comment: It is possible that there is a rule in Direct2D that, when combining geometries in this way, every constituent geometry must be closed to begin with. I don't see it explicit in the documentation - at one point it is implied that the orientation of the segments it s all that matters. Then again, Direct2D documentation leaves a lot to be desired.